# What is this format %20[^\n]?

Tags: c, scanf

Can someone explain me this format in C language?

```
fscanf(file_name,"%20[^\n]%*20c%ld%*c%d%*16c",name,&idE,&cod);
```

I don't understand what  `%20[^\n]` means.

Comment: It says read not more than 20 characters that aren't a newline, null terminating the string in the 21st byte if necessary.  See the [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)
 manual.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And I don't need to write %20[^\n]c ? (namely, it's not need to be with 'c' ?)

Comment: No, `[...]` defines a *character class* which takes the place of `%s` and will match any characters within the `[...]` (in your case the first `'^'` inverts the match so you are literally matching all characters that are NOT `'\n'`.

Comment: The `c` in `%20[^\n]c` would match a literal `c` — but only if the character after the 20 non-newlines was a `c`.  (The character after the scan set match would be a newline, for example, if there aren't 20 characters before the newline.)  Otherwise the matching would fail.  SO, to answer your question, the `%20[^\n]` conversion specification is complete at the `]`; it is not followed by `s` or `c` except when people make mistakes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler linked to the manual. You really should learn how to read in order to learn what you need. It's an important skill.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- "SO, to answer your question...." Is that pun intentional?

Comment: @DavidBowling: Hmmm; no, it was accidental.  Somewhat apt now you've pointed it out, but not what I intended.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- well, I always see puns when I'm feeling punchy....

Comment: Why so many close votes? Seems like a decent question to me.

Comment: @Florian: because it is described in all (reasonably good) C manuals, on `man` pages, and elsewhere.

Comment: I think this scanf format string nicely demonstrates why stdio.h should never be used in professional production code. It isn't really reasonable to assume that _anyone_ should be able to read goo like this, even if they know what all format specifiers mean. Dismissing this as RTFM is to ignore how badly stdio.h was designed in the first place.

Comment: @usr2564301: The fact that a question is answered by material in some document does not mean the question asked for such a document. This question asks what some code means. It does not ask us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments, the `%20[^\n]`scan set  conversion specification means that the code will read not more than 20 characters that aren't a newline, null terminating the string (using the 21st byte if necessary). The scan set conversion is complete at the `]` — there are special rules when you need to include `]` in the scan set.  See the POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) manual for the full details.

Note that there are various scenarios.  First, the scan set won't skip leading white space (and it plus `%c` and `%n` are the only three conversion specifications that don't skip white space).

Suppose that the next character is a newline: the conversion fails because there must be at least one character that matches for it to succeed.

Suppose instead that the next few characters are not newlines, but there is a newline before 20 characters are read.  Those characters will be read into the string, which will be null terminated.

Alternatively, suppose that the next few characters are not newlines, but there is a newline (immediately) after the 20th character.  There will be 20 characters in the string that's read, plus a null terminator, and the newline will be processed by the next part of the format string.  In the question, that's `%*20c`, which means "read 20 characters, including white space, but do not assign to any variable".  If, instead of `%*20c`, the character was `c`, then the match of the `c` would fail; the next character is a newline.  You'd know because `scanf()` would return just 1, not 2 or more.

The other alternative is that there are more than 20 non-newlines to read; 20 of them will be saved into the variable associated with the scan set, and the following characters will be matched (or not) by the subsequent characters or conversion specifications in the format string.

Comment: *Suppose that the next character is a newline: the conversion fails because there must be at least one character that matches for it to succeed.* I didn't get this part.

Comment: I mean I am not getting in which context you said.

Comment: If the first character in the input when `fscanf()` starts processing `%20[^\n]` is a newline, then the scan set fails — it cannot match zero characters.  For the scan set to match, the first character must not be a newline; it can be a space or tab or anything else except a newline.

Comment: *For the scan set to match, the first character must not be a newline*:  if that's the case then doesn't this make this scenario: *"Suppose that the next few characters are not newlines, but there is a newline before 20 characters are read."*, same as the previous one?

Comment: What's the problem?  The 20 is an upper bound.  If there's one letter and a newline, the scan set is content — the letter matches and the newline terminates the scan set (and isn't included in the string). If there are 19 letters (or digits or punctuation, or blanks and tabs) followed by a newline, the scan set is happy and the newline is left in the input. If there are 20 letters (or …) and a newline, the scan set is happy, but doesn't even look at the newline — that's a problem for the next conversion. If there's more than 20 letters (or …), the scan set is happy and the 21st is left behind.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the referred statement. I know how it works but was little confused with the statement.

Comment: Is it clearer now?  I added an "instead" and an "alternatively" to make it clearer that each supposition is separate from the others and not cumulative processing.

Comment: Yes. I got it now. Thanks for the explanations.